# How Do You Insert An Additional Key/Value To An Array of Objects in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord, hash, insert-update

Due to having to do some fancy searching via cookie storage, I've got an array of (Model) objects.

@ads contains

```
[{:id => 9283
:name => "Name Here"
:price => 2000
:phone => "999-999-9999"
}]
```

etc, for multiple objects.  Thus, a two-dimensional array (really resembling a Hash, of course, but Rails is dealing with it in Arrays do to the find() and find_all_by() methods being used.

What I need to do, is on a given Ad page, flag a single object as the "current" Ad so it can be denoted as such in the view.

I've isolated it with

```
@ads.select {|a| a[:id] == id}
```

But if I attempt

```
@ads.select {|a| a[:id] == id}.push :current => true
```

I seem to end up with a new element INSIDE that object element, like so:

@ads then contains

```
[{:id => 9283
:name => "Name Here"
:price => 2000
:phone => "999-999-9999"},
{:current=>true}]
```

How can I add it to the existing attributes for the selected object so that it becomes accessible by simply ad[:current] within the view?  Should I do a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select` is returning an array, but you want a specific hash in the array, so use `find`. Now that you're dealing with a hash, you don't need to `push`, but `merge`

```
@ads.find {|a| a[:id] == id}.merge! :current => true
```